# Can't find type mismatch error in ACCESS vba SQL

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a long query that runs in ACCESS, but when I convert the code to VBA I keep getting a type mismatch error.  I have rebuilt the SQL at least 5 times, and checked everything in the Having clause, all data types match. The VBA COde is an exact match for the code generated in the qbe grid. And since it's a select query I had to fake it out so the it looks like a table. I have created smaller queries that run perfectly. I just can't see the type error. Here is the code and the command that executes it:

```
Dim PivotMaster As String
PivotMaster = "SELECT dbo_Transaction_Table.Account_Number, 
dbo_Transaction_Table.Transaction_Type, dbo_Transaction_Table.Sku," & _
" dbo_Transaction_Table.Date_of_Transaction, 
 dbo_Master_Accounts.Account_Type_2," & _
" Format([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Date_of_Transaction],'yyy') AS [Year]," & 
_
" Format([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Date_of_Transaction],'mmm') AS [Month]," & 
_
" Month([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Date_of_Transaction]) AS MonthNo," & _
" Format([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Date_of_Transaction],'ddd') AS [Day]," & _
" Format([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Time_of_Transaction],'hh') AS [Hour]," & _
" dbo_Transaction_Table.Quantity, [dbo_Transaction_Table]![Amount] AS 
UnitPrice," & _
" dbo_Transaction_Table.Extension, dbo_Transaction_Table.ArAmt," & _
" dbo_Transaction_Table.Balls, dbo_Transaction_Table.Location_Id, 
dbo_Location_Table.Location_Type," & _
" dbo_Location_Table.Location_Description, [dbo_Location_Table]! 
[Location_Type] & " - " & [dbo_Location_Table]![Location_Id] AS Location" & 
_
" FROM ((dbo_Transaction_Table INNER JOIN dbo_Inventory_Table ON 
dbo_Transaction_Table.Sku = dbo_Inventory_Table.Sku)" & _
" INNER JOIN dbo_Location_Table ON dbo_Transaction_Table.Location_Id = 
dbo_Location_Table.Location_Id)" & _
" INNER JOIN dbo_Master_Accounts ON dbo_Transaction_Table.Account_Number = 
dbo_Master_Accounts.Master_ID" & _
" GROUP BY dbo_Transaction_Table.Account_Number," & _
" dbo_Transaction_Table.Transaction_Type, dbo_Transaction_Table.Sku," & _
" dbo_Transaction_Table.Date_of_Transaction, 
dbo_Master_Accounts.Account_Type_2," & _
" Format([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Date_of_Transaction],'yyyy'), 
Format([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Date_of_Transaction],'mmm')," & _
" Month([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Date_of_Transaction]), 
Format([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Date_of_Transaction],'ddd')," & _
" Format([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Time_of_Transaction],'hh'), 
dbo_Transaction_Table.Quantity, [dbo_Transaction_Table]![Amount]," & _
" dbo_Transaction_Table.Extension, dbo_Transaction_Table.ArAmt, 
dbo_Transaction_Table.Balls, dbo_Transaction_Table.Location_Id," & _
" dbo_Location_Table.Location_Type, dbo_Location_Table.Location_Description, 
[dbo_Location_Table]![Location_Type] & " - " & [dbo_Location_Table]! 
[Location_Id]" & _
" HAVING (((dbo_Transaction_Table.Transaction_Type)<>3) AND 
((dbo_Transaction_Table.Extension)>0))"

CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef "PivotMaster", PivotMaster
DoCmd.OpenQuery "PivotMaster"
```

Thanks

Comment: What about your syntax that has a space embedded in it just after "!"? [dbo_Location_Table]! [Location_Type] "

Comment: `Transaction_Type` or `Extension` are strings? (HAVING clause)

Comment: TRansaction _Type is Number and extension is currency

Comment: Using find there is no ! with a space after it.  Which line are you talking about?

Comment: There's a line break that appears to be preceded by a space character after `[dbo_Location_Table]!` on the 18th line. Same thing on the 6th last line.

You also appear to have some line breaks in there in odd places, like after `&` but before `_`... Usually that doesn't happen in the question formatting thing here, so I wonder about whether it's actually in your code...

Comment: I most certainly can find the ! followed by the space! Just search this webpage for that and you will find the two. If they don't exist in the code in your program, then what you have pasted and posted into this question is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just copied and pasted your code but taken out the line breaks that would cause issues if they're in the real version. Not sure how they got in there in the first place, but in case that's the issue:

```
Dim PivotMaster As String
PivotMaster = "SELECT dbo_Transaction_Table.Account_Number," & _ 
" dbo_Transaction_Table.Transaction_Type, dbo_Transaction_Table.Sku," & _
" dbo_Transaction_Table.Date_of_Transaction, dbo_Master_Accounts.Account_Type_2," & _
" Format([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Date_of_Transaction],'yyy') AS [Year]," & _
" Format([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Date_of_Transaction],'mmm') AS [Month]," & _
" Month([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Date_of_Transaction]) AS MonthNo," & _
" Format([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Date_of_Transaction],'ddd') AS [Day]," & _
" Format([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Time_of_Transaction],'hh') AS [Hour]," & _
" dbo_Transaction_Table.Quantity, [dbo_Transaction_Table]![Amount] AS UnitPrice," & _
" dbo_Transaction_Table.Extension, dbo_Transaction_Table.ArAmt," & _
" dbo_Transaction_Table.Balls, dbo_Transaction_Table.Location_Id," & _
" dbo_Location_Table.Location_Type, dbo_Location_Table.Location_Description," & _
" [dbo_Location_Table]![Location_Type] & ' - ' &" & _
" [dbo_Location_Table]![Location_Id] AS Location" & _
" FROM ((dbo_Transaction_Table INNER JOIN dbo_Inventory_Table ON" & _
" dbo_Transaction_Table.Sku = dbo_Inventory_Table.Sku)" & _
" INNER JOIN dbo_Location_Table ON dbo_Transaction_Table.Location_Id =" & _
" dbo_Location_Table.Location_Id)" & _
" INNER JOIN dbo_Master_Accounts ON dbo_Transaction_Table.Account_Number =" & _  
" dbo_Master_Accounts.Master_ID" & _
" GROUP BY dbo_Transaction_Table.Account_Number," & _
" dbo_Transaction_Table.Transaction_Type, dbo_Transaction_Table.Sku," & _
" dbo_Transaction_Table.Date_of_Transaction, dbo_Master_Accounts.Account_Type_2," & _
" Format([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Date_of_Transaction],'yyyy')," & _
" Format([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Date_of_Transaction],'mmm')," & _
" Month([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Date_of_Transaction])," & _
" Format([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Date_of_Transaction],'ddd')," & _
" Format([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Time_of_Transaction],'hh')," & _
" dbo_Transaction_Table.Quantity, [dbo_Transaction_Table]![Amount]," & _
" dbo_Transaction_Table.Extension, dbo_Transaction_Table.ArAmt," & _
" dbo_Transaction_Table.Balls, dbo_Transaction_Table.Location_Id," & _
" dbo_Location_Table.Location_Type, dbo_Location_Table.Location_Description," & _
" [dbo_Location_Table]![Location_Type] & ' - ' [dbo_Location_Table]![Location_Id]" & _
" HAVING (((dbo_Transaction_Table.Transaction_Type)<>3) AND" & _
" ((dbo_Transaction_Table.Extension)>0))"

CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef "PivotMaster", PivotMaster
DoCmd.OpenQuery "PivotMaster"
```

To clarify, (as you may know) if you're putting together a string in VBA for any reason (like building a SELECT statement) you need to close the explicit quotes and add a concatenating ampersand, followed by an underscore to tell VBA that whatever process that line is, the next line is the same part, and *then* hit enter to get yourself a line break.

`end of explicit quote text" & _` ENTER.

Fixing this up showed up some explicit quotes (and lack thereof) that didn't make sense to me. My guess as to your intention was that you wanted something like `SELECT [dbo_Location_Table]![Location_Type] & " - " & [dbo_Location_Table]![Location_Id] AS Location` at a couple of places. The double quotes in the SQL string would confuse VBA though, and it'd think you wanted to subtract one part of the string from the other, which would probably give you a type mismatch. I've replaced them with single quotes, which SQL understands but avoids this confusion by allowing you to make an explicit quote within an explicit quote.

Comment: I commented out my code in the app and tried to copy and paste your correction. But, it has too many continuation characters.  I will rebuild the query following your suggestions and see what happens. But when I built the query I was very careful about continuations, but I could have screwed up.  Wouldn't be the first time.  Thanks

Comment: If you want to retain the 'look & feel' of the continuations you had, you could: (1)  remove ALL continuations; (2) change all lines of the SQL EXCEPT the first to be PivotMaster = PivotMaster  & "...."

Comment: H-uh. I didn't know that was a thing, though I guess it makes sense. I've never had a single string long enough to find out, I guess!